# problem with pdb

Tags: django, pdb

on a django shell i tried

```
from django import forms
class A(forms.Form):
    x = forms.CharField()
ao = A()
import pdb 
pdb.run('ao.as_table')
```

but on the last statement , after hitting continue for the first time i am getting a stacktrace as

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/pdb.pyc in run(statement, globals, locals)
   1218 
   1219 def run(statement, globals=None, locals=None):
-> 1220     Pdb().run(statement, globals, locals)
   1221 
   1222 def runeval(expression, globals=None, locals=None):

/usr/lib/python2.6/bdb.pyc in run(self, cmd, globals, locals)
    370             cmd = cmd+'\n'
    371         try:
--> 372             exec cmd in globals, locals
    373         except BdbQuit:
    374             pass

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/FakeModule.pyc in <module>()

NameError: name 'ao' is not defined
```

what went wrong ? :(

Comment: Use keyword argument locals=locals(), instead of positional argument. With pdb, it can bite sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > > pdb.run('print ao.as_table()', locals())

Basically pass on the locals()  dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Two things.

- First, use the statement argument as a call. i.e `"ao.as_table()"` with `()` as suffix.
- Second, pass a keyword argument `locals=locals()` to the function. You can also pass `globals=globals()`. Don't use locals() as positional argument, as it will get assigned to globals as `run(statement[, globals[, locals]])` takes globals as first argument. So if the first positional argument is `locals()` it will be mistaken as `globals` while running your code.

It should be

> pdb.run('print ao.as_table()' locals=locals())